# can I store the next route complete with path variables?

Tags: angularjs, url, url-parameters

I am implementing deep linking in a system using angular. (User follows link in to system, gets login screen, authenticates, then next step is the page they requested with the link (as opposed to the generic fresh-login-start page)).

In the `$routeChangeStart` event handler I store the next route location in the cookie. After the user authenticates I retrieve the location and send them there.

It works fine for urls without any path variables. For example, if they were trying to get to `mydomain.com/viewAllServices` then they go to the location post login.

It does not work for urls with path variables. For example, if they were trying to get to `mydomain.com/service/123` then post login, they go to `mydomain.com/service/:serviceId`

I can see the parameters in the `next.params` and `next.pathParams` objects in my $routeChangeStart event handler. I can figure out how to replace them programatically, but I wonder if there is a friendlier part of the angular interface that I should be using.

Has anyone else implemented this? Is it necessary to put the values in the url using regex?